# using expression for controller name(ng-controller) in a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Instead of specifying controller name using `ng-controller`I want to specify controller name via an attribute in the directive and then replace it in the template(I want to do it this weird way just to explore AngularJS).

Here is the link to the plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KZgLQ6?p=preview

e.g. of what I am trying to do

```
<sample-drtv ctrl-name="drtvCtrl"></sample-drtv>
```

template(sampleDrtv.html):

```
<div ng-controller="{{ctrlName}}"> 
  <p>{{ptagcontent}}</p>  
</div>
```

Directive code:

```
var myModule = angular.module('ng');

myModule.directive('sampleDrtv',[function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "sampleDrtv.html",
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs){
                $scope.ctrlName = $attrs.ctrlName;
                console.log($scope);
            }
        };

}]);

function drtvCtrl($scope){
  $scope.ptagcontent = "AngularJS Rocks";  
}
```

I am getting this error on my console:

```
Error: Argument '{{ctrlName}}' is not a function, got undefined
```

Any ideas on what should I do so that `ctrlName` is replaced in the expression? I am sure I do not understand concepts of directives completely and so I am doing a mistake?

Comment: what is use case for needing to do use expression to define controller?

Comment: you are just trying to make another ng-controller.there is already one.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Is it so that AngularJS tries to link ng-controller directive first? without replacing the value in the expression. My directive's link function is called after ng-controller's expression is evaluated? Why is it so?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem. And yes, it's imperative that I dynamically declare the controller, as I'm displaying a list of elements of a page. Each element consists of a template and a controller, defined in a CMS.

Comment: Well you can't do it using expression in controller declaration. Look for "ngControllerDirective" in their source code. No handling for expression evaluation is done there. There are workarounds to the problem but they depend upon the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this structure :

```
<sample-drtv></sample-drtv>
```

template(sampleDrtv.html):

```
<div ng-controller="drtvCtrl"> 
  <p>{{ptagcontent}}</p>  
</div>
```

AngularJS Part:

```
var myModule = angular.module('ng');

myModule.directive('sampleDrtv',[function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "sampleDrtv.html"
  };
}]);

function drtvCtrl($scope){
  $scope.ptagcontent = "AngularJS Rocks";  
}
```

See the Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/GwnqK6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for replying. I appreciate your help. I initially followed this approach and certainly this will work. However I am curious about what is the exact reason that I am trying to achieve will not work?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't vote it down. Anyway! I would appreciate if you could help me understand why what I am trying to do won't work technically. Probably if you/someone could explain me how AngularJS handles such situations would help even more. Thanks again!